# ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'NSHumanReadableDescription' in bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, plist

When I upload my project to iTunes Connect. I get Archive upload failed due to the issues listed below. I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. Anyone have an idea?

`ERROR ITMS-90360: "Missing Info.plist value. A value for the key 'NSHumanReadableDescription' in bundle myApp.app/PlugIns/ContentBlocker.appex is required."`

[image]

**Solved**

1. Open Info.plist in your extension
2. Add Key NSHumanReadableDescription
3. Then Add a String Value

[image]

I still not sure on what is supposed to go in the Value field. Can someone shed some light?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW29

Comment: Are you updating the correct plist? You should add this key to your content blocker (extension) plist.

Comment: That's funny you ask. Nothing changed in the plist. I reverted back 20 revisions and was clueless on what changed.